# How to perform certain action when a post is created in Strapi CMS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, content-management-system, strapi

I am using ***Strapi CMS*** for my data handling with a NoSQL database.
So, what I am trying to do is to publish the blog on [Medium](http://medium.com/) also when I publish it on Strapi CMS.

I have all the credentials for publishing it on medium using API.

**So, the question is how to achieve this, how to perform a certain action in Strapi CMS when  a post is created or updated**, so that I can get the data and send to [Medium](http://medium.com/) via POST request.

[image]

Comment: Everything you need to know is here: https://strapi.io/blog/understanding-the-different-types-categories-of-strapi-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research and instruction by [Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5064324/ghosh) I came to know about the webhooks provided by Strapi by default.

These hooks are somewhat same as React Lifecycle Hooks

More about hooks: [Here](https://strapi.io/blog/understanding-the-different-types-categories-of-strapi-hooks)

So for my case I have to add a hook which trigger some action after blog post is created.
So, in `api/blog/models/{blog}.js`, I added this code

```
"use strict";
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async afterCreate(data) {
      const body = {
        title: data.title,
        contentFormat: "markdown",
        content: data.blog_data,
        tags: [],
      };
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.medium.com/v1/users/${process.env.CLIENT_SECRET}/posts?accessToken=${process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify(body),
        }
      );
    },
  },
};
```